# Customizing Material-UI Components with Styled-Components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I am trying to customize the `props` of a material-ui `Grid` component using styled-components. I tried to do something like this:

```
const NavGrid = styled(Grid)`
    direction: 'row';
`
```

But this did not work. So, I was wondering, is there an alternative to doing `<Grid container direction={'row'}>`? Can I customize these properties using styled-components rather than doing it in-line?

I tried attaching `props` to my styled component like this:

```
const NavGrid = styled(Grid).attrs({
    direction: 'row'
})``
```

as described [here](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/2022), but this also did not work.

Comment: Explain more. I don't know if you have Googled or searched other questions yet.

Comment: In this case you're customizing styling, i.e. css, not the props.

Comment: @Clarity yes but is there some way to customize the props through styled-components rather than doing it inline?

Comment: Maybe you'd do it with `attrs` method, but I'm not sure: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs

Comment: @Clarity I tried using `attrs` but it didn't work for some reason although it seems to be what I am looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'direction' Prop in Material-UI Grid Defines the **flex-direction** style property. 
So, if you want to override that style using styled-components, you need to use **flex-direction instead of direction**.
Here is an example:

```
const MyGrid = styled(Grid)`
  flex-direction: column;
`
```

Good luck.